# c# Creating header of file name and size while sending file in socket connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have successfully using the below to send file size info from server to client in my socket connection:

For server:

```
    public void SendFiles(Socket client, string filePath)
    {
        byte[] imgBuff = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var length = imgBuff.Length;

        Send(client, BitConverter.GetBytes(length)); //Send file size in header info
        Send(client, imgBuff);  //Send the file
    }
```

For Client, I do two times receive callback:

```
    private void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveHeaderCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ReceiveHeaderCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("## Begin ReceiveHeaderCallback");
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            state.fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
            _Buff = new byte[state.fileSize];
            _totBytesRead = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("## File size = " + state.fileSize);

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
               new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                Buffer.BlockCopy(state.buffer, 0, _Buff, _totBytesRead, bytesRead);

                _totBytesRead += bytesRead;

                if (_totBytesRead < state.fileSize)
                {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\abc.png", _Buff);
                    Debug.WriteLine("## File receiving complete. File created at ");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Now if I want to send file name to the client too, what is the best way to do it?

Is it I add it to the header? How do we add it?

Or I send separately and in clients side I create another callback for it?

Comment: You could use a similar approach for the file name, which is just a variable length string, like the file is a variable length file - send the length of the string, then the string itself.

Comment: Ian, you mean I add it to the header along the file size? How to we do that?

Comment: Encode the filename string to a byte array, then send the array length followed by the array.  Just like you do with the file data.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it’s wise to assume that the first time your client finishes doing a read it will have read only the bytes the server sent as a header. You’d be better off defining a specification here; decide something arbitrary, like the data that is sent shall be

```
<length>:<file name>:<file bytes>
```

Then your client can receive and reassemble the file

Or implement an existing protocol, like http

Comment: U mean separate the data in semicolon? When the client received just split the bytes when read the semicolon? Its difficult to compare with http because http is in string, but my data is in bytes.

Comment: If you use separators, don't use one that's valid in a file name, like semicolon!  Colon is fine.

Comment: Are you sure the data in bytes form won't contain a colon symbol?

Comment: String, bytes, it’s all bytes! Strings are made of bytes.. YOU DECIDE what you want this protocol to look like. Use xml, use http, used fixed width.. it’s arbitrary => YOU DECIDE

Comment: I'm using bytes so my info is in hex... so there no 0x3A which is colon in the data right?

Comment: If you don’t like colon, use a different byte. If you think the data will contain 0x3A either pack it differently so it doesn’t, or use another byte. Use fixed width (the first ten bytes are the length, the next 200 bytes are the name, then the data.) “But what if someone gives a name longer than 200?” -> refuse them/ make your protocol 300 bytes/ truncate it. You’re designing this protocol, you know how the system works, what the files are like etc, you make the rules. For what it’s worth, I’d just implement http- text headers, two new lines, image data. You can then test with common tools